# Python Panel Render 1 of 4 scenes?

Tags: python, rendering, scene

How do I target a specific scene to render?

I note from the nodes button that the path is as follows:

```
bpy.ops.render.render(layer="RenderLayer", scene="Van")
```

Can anyone tell me how I would apply this to a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question,in relation to setting operator properties in a draw method,  is a duplicate, but can never find it.

Here is a sample draw method that adds a button to render the layer "RenderLayer" of all scenes in blend.

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
        op = layout.operator("render.render", text=scene.name)
        op.layer = "RenderLayer"
        op.scene = scene.name
```